# Quotes not in the right place for array

Tags: php, header

I keep getting this error and I have tried putting quotes around the actual array, periods, nothing has worked.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 8

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$record = "SELECT `Name`, `Type`, `Size`, `Content` FROM election_candidates WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($record);

foreach ($result as $results) {
    header("Content-length: $results['Size']");  <---Line 8
    header("Content-type: $results['Type']");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$results['Name']");

    // echo $results['Size'];

    echo $results['Content'];
}

exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [complex (curly) syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), [symple syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) or the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
// Added isset() and intval()
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
// Removed quotes from 'id'=...
$record = "SELECT `Name`, `Type`, `Size`, `Content` FROM election_candidates WHERE `ID` = $id";
$result = $db->query($record);

foreach ($result as $results) {
    // complex (curly) syntax
    header("Content-length: {$results['Size']}");
    // simple syntax (without quotes)
    header("Content-type: $results[Type]");
    // using concatenation operator
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$results['Name']);

    // echo $results['Size'];

    echo $results['Content'];
}

exit();
```

In addition you should escape `$_GET['id']` and you don't need quotes for an integer in MySQL. I've corrected these two "problems" in the above code.

You could also add `LIMIT 1` to the SQL query and remove the `foreach` loop ;)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help :) I wasn't aware that putting those quotes around my integer would make me vulnerable to sqli. Also, why are we using curly brackets again?

Comment: Actually the quotes weren't really a problem (MySQL handles them correctly). The problem was that anybody could write SQL code into the GET variable `id` which then gets executed in the SQL query! We are using the curly syntax because you want to access an associative array.

Comment: @wowzuzz As alexisdm said in another answer, you can even omit the quotes: `header("Content-length: $results[Size]");`. That's the [simple syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).

Answer (score 1):

Since the key is  literal string, you can remove the internal quotes:

```
header("Content-length: $results[Size]");
```

See the examples in the [simple syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) section.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
header("Content-length: $results['Size']");
```

you'll have to write

```
header("Content-length: ".$results['Size']);
```

or

```
header("Content-length: {$results['Size']}");
```

you'll have to do the same in line 9 and 10

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use array subscripts inside interpolated strings. You have two options:

```
'Content-Length: ' . $results['Size']
"Content-Length: {$results['Size']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're nesting array accessors within a string, I think you want this syntax:

```
"Content-length: {$results['Size']}"
```